# Filter is not working in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

My other filter is not working.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="result in pagedResults | filter:selectedBuilders | filter:selectedBedrooms" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
        [...]
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Filter:selectedBuilders** is Working. But **Filter:selectedBedrooms** is not working

```
<select ng-model="selectedBedRooms" ng-change="selectBedRooms()">
   <option value="">Bedrooms</option>
   <option value="1">1 Bedroom</option>
   <option value="2">2 Bedrooms</option>
</select>
```

Here is the JS.

```
$scope.selectBedRooms = function () {
   if ($scope.selectedBedRooms) {
            $scope.selectedBedrooms = $scope.selectedBedRooms;
   } else {
            $scope.selectedBedrooms = "";
   }
}
```

JSON.
[Here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoK4u.png)

```
data: Array(55)
  0 {
    Address : "Estuary"
    Baths : 2
    Beds : 3
    Builder: "/media/1394/logo.png"
    BuilderComp : "LB Homes"
    ContentId : 3130
  }
  ...
```

I was wondering why *selectBedrooms* is not working and *selectBuilders* is working?

Am I missing something?
Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
    <li ng-repeat="result in pageResults | filter: selectFilter"></li>
```

**Controller**

```
    $scope.selectFilter = function (result) 
    {
  return(result.Beds==$scope.selectedBedRooms && result.Builder == $scope.selectedBuilder);
    }
```